# Using age in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in my postgresql 8.4 database like this:

```
id(serial), event_type_id(id, foreign key), ts(timestamp)
```

I have two event type id's that I need to see the age between.

```
Event_type_id 1 = Arrive
Event_type_id 2 = Leaves
```

example data

```
 id | event_type_id |             ts             
----+---------------+----------------------------
 21 |             6 | 2012-04-03 16:02:18.739274
 20 |             5 | 2012-04-03 08:44:13.244287
```

I want to group these by day and see how many hours per day it is.

can someone point me in the direction how to group and calculate the age?

So far I have this, but I need to generate a series to join on or something similar

**Solution**
Don't know if it's best practice but it works for me.

```
SELECT dx, age(max(ts), min(ts)) 
from generate_series('2012-04-01', '2012-04-14', interval '1 day') as dx 
left join events on (ts >= dx and ts < dx + '23 hours 59 minutes' and event_type_id in (5,6)) 
group by dx 
order by dx;
```

Comment: Is `id` the primary key for the table? Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: I feel you have to rethink your schema.Will it be simple if you have the timestamp in the event table?

Comment: edit post with example data and my current sql

Comment: How do you know that the row with `id=20` "belongs" to `id=21`? What if you have more than two rows in that table?

Comment: Sorry for bad data example. Updated it now with better data. I know that every day there is one event for event_Type_id 6 and 5. This is just a temporary table for me to check some data and not a application to be used so the design may have some flaws.

Comment: Upper limit in your solution is incorrect. Try: `... JOIN events ON ts >= dx and ts < dx + interval '1d' AND ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
select age(max(ts), min(ts)), ts::date as date
from events
where event_type_id in (5,6)
group by date;
```

But your question is not clear. I assume you mean that you have a table (not a database) like this:

```
create table events (
  id serial,
  event_type_id int references event_types,
  ts timestamp
);
```

And you need to calculate an interval between first and last event of type 5 or 6 for every date.